# How to move a point along a line

Tags: linear-algebra

Help me understand *intuitively* how one might move a point along a line. I'm not able to follow [various](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/436788/476642) [solutions](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/175906/476642). These solutions detail steps to follow but I'm not understanding *why* these steps are laid out/suggested. (It may be a good disclaimer that my math education taught me to memorize theorems and not how to apply them).

Help me work from where I am at to what I need to understand to move a point along a line.

[image: Points A and B on a 2D plane]

1. We have 2 points, A and B. A is at (0, 2) and B is at (4, 1).
2. Building from the Pythagorean theorem, the distance between points A and B is $\sqrt{(1-2)^2 + (4-0)^2}$.
3. Simplifying results in $\sqrt{(-1)^2 + (4)^2}$.
4. Simplifying results in $\sqrt{1 + 16}$.
5. Simplifying results in $\sqrt{17}$.
6. Simplifying results in ~4.12.

I can get this far, but then I do not know where to go.

Let's say I want to move 2 units *away* from point A, I could approach it like this.

1. Since the distance from A to B is ~4, I should find an x-value halfway between A and B; I choose 2. $(0 + 4) / 2$.
2. In order to find the y-value at a given x, I need to know the slope of the line, so I remember that the slope is $(y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1)$.
3. Simplifying results in $(1 - 2) / (4 - 0)$.
4. Simplifying results in $-1 / 4$.
5. The slope of the line is $-\frac{1}{4}$.

I can now find the y-value of the line at an x-value of 2.

1. Solve $y = mx + b$.
2. Simplifying results in $y = -\frac{1}{4}*2 + 2$.
3. Simplifying results in $y = -\frac{1}{2} + 2$.
4. Simplifying results in $y = -\frac{1}{2} + \frac{4}{2}$.
5. Simplifying results in $y = \frac{3}{2}$ = $1.5$.

This approach is *naive*, but it's all I can come up on my own. It also doesn't work if the line is vertical because there is no midpoint x-value we can use.

Answer (score 2):

If you move $4$ units horizontally, you move $1$ unit vertically, and $\sqrt{17}$ units obliquely.

Now everything is proportional, and

if you move $\dfrac4{\sqrt{17}}$ units horizontally, you move $\dfrac1{\sqrt{17}}$ unit vertically, and $1$ unit obliquely.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you explain _why_ the horizontal distance or vertical distance is divided by the total distance between two points?

Comment: @Zac: everything is proportional (similarity in triangles).

Comment: I still do not understand. I understand proportions between _other_ triangles but not one itself.

Answer (score 0):

The locus of points at constant distance from a given point is a circle, with the equation $(x-x_c)^2+(y-y_c)^2=r^2$, with subscript $c$ denoting the value at the centre (your given, starting point) and $r$ the radius of the circle (your desired distance).

Now you want the points on this circle which are also on your line - this is simply their intersection.

You can then determine the equation of the line, use your preferred method for solving the resulting set of simultaneous equations (if using the line $y=mx+c$, substitution of $y$ followed by simplification and solution of the quadratic is straightforward) giving you two values for the $x$-ordinate of your new point.

Use the equations to find the $y$-values, then use your knowledge of the relative locations of the lines, and any other information about how you are moving to your new point, to choose the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the intercept theorem, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercept_theorem From this you get
$$\frac{\sqrt{17}-2}{\sqrt{17}}=\frac{4-x}{4},$$
hence $x=8/\sqrt{17}$ which then may be substituted in the equation of the line through $A$ and $B$ or use the theorem again.  In either case you get $y=2-4/\sqrt{17}$.

Answer (score 0):

If $l=\overline{AB}$, then the coordinates of a point $P$ at a distance $|t|$ from $A$, on the same side as $B$ for $t>0$ and on the other side if $t<0$, can be written as:
$$
P=A+{t\over l}(B-A),
$$
where the sum or difference of two points is computed coordinate-wise, as you do with vectors.

In your example: $B=(0,2)$, $A=(4,1)$, $l=\sqrt{17}$, one gets:
$$
P=(4,1)+{t\over\sqrt{17}}[(0,2)-(4,1)]=
(4,1)+{t\over\sqrt{17}}(-4,1)=
\left(4-4{t\over\sqrt{17}},1+{t\over\sqrt{17}}\right).
$$
A geometric proof of that relies on similar triangles and is not difficult. If you are familiar with vectors, you can observe that $(B-A)/l$ is a unit vector in the direction $\vec{AB}$.

EDIT.

Sketch of proof (see figure below).
$$
{PK\over PA}={BH\over BA}\implies
{y_P-y_A\over t}={y_B-y_A\over l}\implies
y_P=y_A+{t\over l}(y_B-y_A),
$$
and the analogous for $x$ coordinates. Of course you should check this works for all possible relative positions of $A$, $B$ and $P$.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you explain how you got to this formula? I'm not seeing the connection, but I assume it's related to a proof on similar triangles.

Comment: @Zac See my edit.